# show that $R \times S$ has the structure of a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $R,S$ rings,then the set $R \times S$,provided with the "operations by coordinates" has the structure of a ring.

$a,c \in R, b,d \in S$
$$(a,b)*(c,d)=(a*c,b*d)$$
$$a*c \in R, \text{since R is a ring}$$
$$b*d \in S, \text{since S is a ring}$$
where $*$ is an operation.

Is that the answer of the exercise or am I wrong??

Comment: You have to verify the ring axioms.

Comment: So isn't it as I have written it above,where $*$ is once $-$ and once $\cdot$?or do I have to prove it otherwise?

Comment: @evinda: you have not verified any axioms, only written the definition.

Comment: @evinda what is the definition of a ring?  Show that it applies.

Comment: Couldn't I show it,by using this:
$$ \text{If } x,y \in R \text{ and } x-y \in R \text{ and } x \cdot y \in R, \text{ then } R \text{ is a ring.}$$
?

Comment: @evinda A ring has more structure than that. It needs to be associative under multiplication and an abelian group under addition.  Depending on your text, it may also need to have a multiplicative identity.

Answer (score 1):

As other have remarked you must actually check all axioms of rings (some $8$ or so) for the new structure. I'll just explain why in practice few people actually go through the whole list to do the checking, since this is quite boring. This is because all axioms of (unitary, commutative, if one wants) rings can be written in the form: for all $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, each running over *all* elements of the ring, one has
$$
  \text{some expression}(x_1,\ldots,x_n) =
  \text{some other expression}(x_1,\ldots,x_n).
$$
It takes a bit of care to get all the axioms in this form; one should avoid saying "there exists an element that is the neutral element for addition", but rather one should include the symbol $0$ in the language of rings (a constant, in other words a nullary operator) and say: "for all $x$ in the ring $x+0=x$" which is of the proper form. The same goes for the neutral element $1$ for multiplication. (Note that the axiom that distinguishes fields from rings, which stipulates the existence of multiplicative inverses for *nonzero* elements, cannot possibly be brought into this form, which explains why a direct product of fields does *not* define a field.) Given that all axioms to be checked are of this form, and that equality in $R\times S$ satisfies $(r_1,s_1)=(r_2,s_2)\iff r_1=r_2\land s_1=s_2$, it is easy to see that checking any axiom in $R\times S$ just amounts to checking that the same axiom holds for the first components of all elements involved and for their second components, which just means that the axiom holds both in $R$ and in $S$, and this was true by hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have only repeated how the operations are defined. You must explicitly show this definition makes $R\times S$ a ring. For example, show $0_{R\times S}=(0_R,0_S)$ is the additive identity of $R\times S$ by showing that 
$$(a,b) +_{R\times S} 0_{R\times S }=0_{R\times S } +_{R\times S } (a,b) =(a,b)$$
for each element $(a,b)$ of $R\times S$.

Answer (score 0):

To show that $R\times S$ is a ring under the operations of coordinates, all you need to do is verify the following claims (the "ring axioms"):

1. $R\times S$ is closed under $+$.
2. $+$ is associative.
3. $+$ is commutative.
4. There is an additive identity for $+$ (i.e. a $0$ element).
5. For any  $(r,s)\in R\times S$, there is an element $-(r,s)$

These first five axioms say that $R\times S$ with the operation $+$ forms an abelian group.
Next, check these axioms:

1. $R\times S$ is closed under $\times$. (You showed this in your question.)
2. $\times$ is associative.
3. $\times$ distributes over multiplication on the left and on the right, i.e. if $a,b,c\in R\times S$ then $a(b+c) = ab + ac$ and $(b+c)a = ba + ca$.

These are all straightforward to check.